# How to implement custom spell checker in text area?

Tags: javascript

anyone can you please explain the way to implement the spell checker functionality in text area or tinyMCE editor.

Answer (score 1):

Browser already have those functionality.
For textarea:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

because it is same as `<textarea spellcheck="true"></textarea>`

But you need to put attributes for tinyMce editor like:

```
 browser_spellcheck: true,
 gecko_spellcheck: true,
```